# How to pass user input variables in my Java code?

Tags: java

```
//Inventory Items classs
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryItems {

    public int sackrice = 4;
    public int animalfeed = 12;
    public int trayeggs = 15;
    public int bottlemilk = 9;

    ItemSupplier supple = new ItemSupplier();
    public void inventoryItem() {
        System.out.println("\nAvailable items:\n");
        sackrice = sackrice + supple.getRice();
        System.out.println("Sack of rice: " + sackrice);
        if(sackrice < 10)
        System.out.println("Sack of rice low, please restock");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Animal feed: " + animalfeed);
        if(animalfeed < 10)
            System.out.println("Animal feed low, please restock");
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Tray of eggs: " + trayeggs);
        if(trayeggs < 15)
            System.out.println("Tray of eggs low, please restock");
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Bottle of milk: " + bottlemilk);
        if(bottlemilk < 15)
            System.out.println("Bottle of milk low, please restock");
        System.out.println();
        press();
    }

    public static void press(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press Enter to continue...");
        String enter = input.nextLine();
    }
}

//Item Supplier class

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemSupplier {
    public int z;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void ricesupplier() {
        System.out.println("How many sacks of rice would you like to 
    order?");
        z = scan.nextInt();
    }
    public int getRice() {
        return z;
    }

    public void feedsupplier() {

    }
    public void eggsupplier() {

    }
    public void milksupplier()   {

   }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryManager{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;

    do {
        System.out.println("Input option:\n" + "\n1. Check inventory" + "\n2. Search item supplier" + "\n3. Exit\n");       
        x = scan.nextInt();
        switch(x) {
                case 1:
                    InventoryItems items = new InventoryItems();
                    items.inventoryItem();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ItemSupplier supply = new ItemSupplier();
                    do {
                        System.out.println("\nChoose supplier:\n" + "\n1. Rice supplier\n" + "2. Animal feed supplier\n" + "3. Egg supplier\n" + "4. Milk supplier\n" + "5. Back\n");
                        y = scan.nextInt();
                        switch(y) {
                            case 1:
                            supply.ricesupplier();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Invalid option");
                                break;
                        }
                    break;
                    } while (y != 5);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Program closed");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option");
                    break;
        }
    } while(x != 3);
}
}
```

The "z" I get from getRice() is 0. It only takes the declared but initialized z. How do I get the "z" that was inputed in ricesupplier() method? Specifically, here: `System.out.println("How many sacks of rice would you like to order?")` and here `z = scan.nextInt()`.

I'm really just a beginner. A lot of parts are still incomplete. I need to finish this problem first before I can proceed.

Comment: You are not using the method ```ricesupplier()``` that is why ```z``` is always 0

Comment: If I use ricesupplier() method, it will also print "How many.." and ask for z.

Comment: I only want to get the "z" value.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: y = scan.nextInt();
switch(y) {
 case 1:
  supply.ricesupplier();
I used ricesupplier () in my main method.

Comment: Kindly include your main method

Comment: @Watson It's a good habit to always make sure a method name contains a verb, e.g. `ricesupplier()` would be `orderRice()` or something.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a direct answer to your question but here's some hints in order to improve your code and eventually solve your problem.

- You should not make a new `InventoryItems` every time the user's input is 1. This will result into printing the initial inventory items, thus making your user order an item is useless
- You should not make a new `ItemSupplier` every time the user's input is 2.
- You don't need `ItemSupplier` in your `InventoryItems`
- You don't need the variable `z` in `ItemSupplier`, you can directly return the input of the user in `ricesupplier()` method
- thus if the user's input is 2 then you can just call `ricesupplier()` method and add it's return to the current `items.sackrice`

Comment: If I immediately call the ricesupplier() in InventoryItems, then it would ask for orders as well. I used InventoryItems as a class to show items, not to ask orders.